# How do I solve for the gain (MOSFET+Capacitor)?

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, feedback

[image: Circuit]

So I came across this circuit in my analog electronics course. I am not sure on how to account for the capacitors and I couldn't find a similar circuit anywhere else. So how do I solve this circuit for gain?

Answer (score 0):

The most direct way is to use nodal or loop relations. 
1) (Vin-Vx)*C1*s=(Vx-Vo)*C2*s
2) (Vx-Vo)*C2*s=Vx*gm+Vo*go
Eliminate Vx. Answer above is low frequency so let s->0 in solution.

Full solution is
Vo/Vin=C1s{1/(C1s+C2s)}*(C2s-gm)*{1/(go+C2s)}/{1-C2s*{1/(C1s+C2s)}*(C2s-gm)*{1/(go+C2s)}
where go=1/ro with gm models the mos transistor

Cancel out 's' terms in cap division factors, drop out C2s in (C2s-gm) factor and finally let s=0 in final to get solution you are looking for.

The full solution is best found using dpi/sfg as shown in Feedback in Analog Circuits by A. Ochoa